# How can ik change the interval of setInterval while running

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Iam making get requests with an interval. On page load i want an interval of 2000, but after 1 get request the interval has to be changed to 20000. What is the best approach in this case ?

```
$(document).ready(function(){

setInterval(function(){

    $.ajax({

        type: 'GET',
        url : "{% url "messages" object.id %}",
        success: function(response){
            console.log(response);
            $("#display").empty();
            for (var key in response.messages)

                {
                    var temp = "<div class='container manager' style='color:black'><b>" + response.messages[key].werknemer_naam ;
                    
                }

        },
        error: function(response){
            alert('An error occured')
        }
    });
},2000);
})
```

Comment: Make the first delay a setTimeout, then create the setInterval

Comment: Another option is you can save your intervals as variables or push them to an array.  Then you can set and clear them by id.

Comment: Just wanted to point out that you got stuck by focusing on the wrong approach. This can be easily solved without changing the intervals delay (which isn't possible anyway).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't change the interval, all you can do is clear it and call `setInterval` again with the new value. But you can save a bit of code by defining the callback function separately. In your case, I'd probably do this:

```js
function makeRequest() {
  // make the request
}

setTimeout(() => {
  makeRequest();
  setInterval(makeRequest, 20000);
}, 2000);
```

So it would wait 2000ms, *then* make the first request and set the request to run every 20000 from then on.

Answer (score 0):

1. Create a boolean set to false outside the setInterval block.
2. Create another variable w/ the default interval time.
3. When the first response comes in, set the boolean to true.
4. With the new true value, the setInterval variable changes to a new value.

Comment: Using a variable and changing it after the setInterval call has no effect.

Comment: No that is not working, it wil stay on the default interval